# this.props.children not rendering despite existing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm writing a component with sub-components, and when I call `this.props.children` in each of the sub-components, no JSX is rendered. If I `console.log` them, I can verify that they do exist and that they are absolutely correct.

```
class Modal extends Component {
  ...
  renderHead() {
    // This checks whether this sub-component was rendered
    const head = findByType(this.props.children, Head);
    if (!head) {
      return null;
    }

    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
```

full code: [source](https://pastebin.com/ww3S756V)

Instantiating the sub-component:

```
const Head = () => null;
...
Modal.Head = Head;
```

The outer code calling this component:

```
<Modal>
  <Modal.Head>
    Hi
  </Modal.Head>
</Modal>
```

Console.log `this.props.children`

[image: This.props]

What am I doing wrong? Nothing shows up and inspecting the element reveals an empty `<div>` is rendered with nothing inside of it...

EDIT - Linked full Modal component code: [source](https://pastebin.com/ww3S756V)

Comment: Please include your entire `Modal` component and how you are using it. It's not easy to say what might be wrong from the code currently in your question.

Comment: Just edited and linked to the full code.

Comment: Are you sure `findByType` is working correctly? Could you post that code in your question, as well?

Comment: I don't really think thats needed. I'm only using the result of findByType to see if `<Modal.whatever>` was actually called and it does in fact work. I don't use it's value in render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a dumb one. My mistake was using `this` when I should have been using `head` or `body` or `footer` when referencing children.

Changed to `head.props.children`. Sorry, that was my mistake.